# django form field label as html

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am loading a form using following template tag -

```
{{ form.as_table }}
```

Form got radio button, and the select items for it got using following form field -

forms.RadioSelect(choices=[ (o.choice_value, o.choice_name) for o in Choice.objects.filter()])

one of the choice_name got html elements into it, which gets loaded with those tags instead of actual HTML rendering.

If it would be regular template variable, I can do {{ some_variable|safe }} to load it as HTML, any idea how to do it in case of form tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template tags and filters anywhere in your Python code, just import them and use them:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import safe

forms.RadioSelect(choices=[(o.choice_value, safe(o.choice_name))
    for o in Choice.objects.filter()])
```